# JSP Redirection Issue according to Condition

Tags: java, jsp

I have different clubs with different domains as below :

```
Kid club = kidclub.google.mobi
Youth Club = youthclub.yahoo.mobi
Adult Club=adult.godaddy.mobi
Elderly Club = elderly.google.mobi
```

Redirection Settings are as below (sample redirection settings):

```
1. Kid Club should redirect to Youth Club 
2. Youth Club should redirect to Adult Club
3. Adult Club should redirect to Elderly Club
4. Elderly Club should redirect to Kid club
```

Problem Scenario:
If user tries to subscribe Kid Club then, if he is not registered to this club, he is forwarded to domain "kidclub.google.mobi".  But if he is already registered then he should be redirected to another club Youth Club  (youthclub.yahoo.mobi) AS defined in the settings. And if he is again already registered to Youth Club then he should be automatically redirected to Adult Club (adult.godaddy.mobi). This goes on until to the club he is not registered with.

I have the following code which just can redirect to a single club but I am not able to check the condition if the user is subscribed to second club or not.

```
//ClubDao.isActive(user,club) returns TRUE if user is active to that club and 
FALSE if user is inactive. 

if( user != null && club != null && ClubDao.isActive(user, club))
{
redirectReturningUser( request, response,domain );
}

void redirectReturningUser( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response,Domain currentDomain )
{
String redirectToUrl = currentDomain.getDefaultUrl();

if( "kidclub.google.mobi".equals( currentDomain.getDefaultUrl() ) )
   redirectToUrl = "youthclub.yahoo.mobi";
else if( "youthclub.yahoo.mobi".equals( currentDomain.getDefaultUrl() ) )
   redirectToUrl = "adult.godaddy.mobi";
else if( "adult.godaddy.mobi".equals( currentDomain.getDefaultUrl() ) )
   redirectToUrl = "elderly.google.mobi";
else if( "elderly.google.mobi".equals( currentDomain.getDefaultUrl() ) )
   redirectToUrl = "kidclub.google.mobi";

       doRedirect(response, "http://"+redirectToUrl );
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do if user is subscribed to another league?

Comment: @Nambari,  redirect to another club until he reaches to the club he is not subscribed to.

Comment: @Nambari there cannot be the condition where the user is subscribed to all 4 clubs. At least one club he won't be subscribed. So, for above example if he is not subscribed to Adult Club then he is shown adult.godaddy.mobi  web page.

Comment: What do you want to do if the user subscribed to several clubs?

Comment: @Roman.. User sends request to subscribe a club for example Youth Club, and the code should check if he is already subscribed to that club or not. if he is new to this club he is shown youthclub.yahoo.mobi webpage.

But if he is already subscribed to this club then he should be automatically redirected to Adult Club (adult.godaddy.mobi) webpage. And again the code should check if he is already subscribed to Adult Club, if he is already subscribed to this club then he should be automatically redirected to elderly.google.mobi  webpage.

Comment: @Roman the code should continuously check if the user has subscribed to club or not.. if he is not then he is shown that club's webpage but if he is, then he should be redirected to another club webpage as per the settings..

Comment: @Madan All redirects you should associate with the club which user belongs to. How do you build that map depends on your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used while loop to solve this issue and it worked out!!

```
while(registered==true){

   //code for redirectconditions
    .......................

    checkifRegistered==false??
     }
  redirectUser(club URLLink);
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

What if you map each `Club` to the url string and then retrieve the string when the user membership against the club is established.

```
  static Map<Club, String> redirectMap= new LinkedHashMap<Club, String>();

  static  {
    redirectMap.put(new Club("kidclub.google.mobi"), "youthclub.yahoo.mobi");
    redirectMap.put(new Club("youthclub.yahoo.mobi"), "adult.godaddy.mobi");
    redirectMap.put(new Club("adult.godaddy.mobi"), "elderly.google.mobi");
    redirectMap.put(new Club("elderly.google.mobi"), "kidclub.google.mobi");

  }

  void redirectReturningUser (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    Map<Club, String> tmpRredirectMap = new LinkedHashMap<Club, String>();
    for (Map.Entry<Club, String> entry: redirectMap.entrySet()){

      Club club = entry.getKey();
      String redirectUrl = entry.getValue();
      if( user != null && club != null && ClubDao.isActive(user, club))  {
        tmpRredirectMap.put(club, redirectUrl);
      }
    }
    boolean done = false;
    String tempUrl = domain.getDefaultUrl();
    int count = redirectMap.size();
    Club tempClub = new Club(tempUrl);
    do {
      if (tmpRredirectMap.keySet().contains(tempClub)){
        tempClub = new Club(redirectMap.get(tempClub));
        count--;
      } else {
        done = true;
      }
    } while (! done && count > 0);
    redirectReturningUser(request, response, tempClub.getName());
  }
  void redirectReturningUser( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response, String redirectUrl ) throws IOException {

    doRedirect(response, "http://"+redirectUrl );
  }

  private void doRedirect(HttpServletResponse response, String s) throws IOException {
    response.sendRedirect(s);
  }
```

Comment: @Roman.. Thanks for the code.. But I need a solution where it checks continuously if user is subscribed to club or not.. if he is not subscribed then only redirection is done else it will keep on checking which club user is not subscribing!!

Comment: @MadanMadan I have given you an idea, I don't want to write an application for you.

Comment: @Roman.. no not the application.. thanks for the code.. but it works only for a single redirection but not for condition checking if user has subscribed to a second club or not.. which is my main problem!!

Comment: @MadanMadan Iterate through the clubs to check if user belongs to, save results in the temporary map. Then simulate redirects through the loop. When finished redirect to the last location. Don't forget to create `equals` and `hashCode` methods for `Club`.